# cpu usage while running binaries of same code with different size

Tags: linux, gcc, cpu

I have generated one binary(20 MB) with gcc with -g option after that have compiled same code with gcc without -g option and generated binary of 8 MB,So my question is is there any effect in cpu usage if I run both(20MB,8MB) binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the debug version runs slower. It is problematic tracing race conditions

Comment: But why can you explain me in detail? Thanks for your answer

Comment: The debug version has more instructions (hence the size of the binaries).